# SWIG: Redifining signature of a class method to use custom typemaps

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a toy model of a class with a method which takes two integers and pushes them to a vector (passed by reference). I also have some custom typemaps which modify in/out arguments and most importantly modify the vector argument to be an output argument for python. So far, when I declare this as a function outside of the class, I am able to redefine it in the interface file to use the typemaps without re-declaring, but I cannot do the same for the class method.

My toy model looks like this:

```cpp
/* example.hpp */
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void some_func(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* res);

class SampleClass
{
public:
  ...
    void two_args(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* vec);
  ...

};
```

```cpp
/* example.cpp */

void some_func(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* res){
    res->push_back(x);
    res->push_back(y);
}
void SampleClass::two_args(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* vec){
     vec->push_back(x);
     vec->push_back(y);
}
```

```
/* interface.i */
%module example

%{
    #include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

%template(doublevector) std::vector<double>;
%template(intvector) std::vector<int>;

/* NOTE: This mostly works but not for constructor */
%apply std::vector<double> *INPUT {std::vector<double>* };


/* Ignore vec as input argument and set it to a temp val */
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::vector<int>* VecOutInt (std::vector<int> tmp){
    $1 = &tmp;
}

/* Return a list to python */
%typemap(argout) std::vector<int>* VecOutInt {
    size_t size = (*$1).size();
    $result = PyList_New(size);
    Py_ssize_t idx = 0;
    for (idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx){
        PyObject *o = PyLong_FromLong($1->at(idx));
        PyList_SetItem($result, idx, o);
}
}
void some_func(int x, int y, std::vector<int> * VecOutInt); // Redifinition works fine here.
void SampleClass::two_args(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* VecOutInt); // But not here. (I guess?)
%include "example.hpp"

/* python */
>>> a = ex.some_func(1, 2)
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> ex_cls = ex.SampleClass().two_args(1, 2)
default constructor!
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                TypeError: two_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vec'
```

Essentially, I am trying to apply this typemap to this particular method, or at least its particular signature (but more focused on the method part). I've found this thread [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/mailman/swig-user/thread/0d094fab-fad6-c3c1-43f4-55dac8e2f199@beam.ltd.uk/) from the mailing lists which is pretty much the problem I am having but with no actual/definitive answers.
Is there a way to redefine class methods in the interface file?
Changing the C++ code is not an option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example.  In this case all you need is to apply an `OUTPUT` typemap:

**example.hpp**

```cpp
#include <vector>

void some_func(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* res);

class SampleClass
{
public:
    void two_args(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* vec);
};
```

**example.cpp**

```cpp
#include "example.hpp"

void some_func(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* res) {
    res->push_back(x);
    res->push_back(y);
}

void SampleClass::two_args(int x, int y, std::vector<int>* vec) {
     vec->push_back(x);
     vec->push_back(y);
}
```

**example.i**

```cpp
%module example

%{
#include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%template(intvector) std::vector<int>;

%apply std::vector<int>* OUTPUT {std::vector<int>*};
%include "example.hpp"
```

Output:

```
>>> import example as e
>>> e.some_func(1, 2)
(1, 2)
>>> s = e.SampleClass()
>>> s.two_args(3, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Note that if you have some vectors as inputs and some as outputs, then you can `%apply` the `OUTPUT` typemap explicitly by naming the parameter, e.g.:

```cpp
%apply std::vector<int>* OUTPUT {std::vector<int>* vec};
%apply std::vector<int>* OUTPUT {std::vector<int>* res};
```

And even if the parameters are the same name in two functions but one is used as an input and one is used as an output, if they differ by `const` you can still apply them separately:

```cpp
%apply std::vector<int>* INPUT {const std::vector<int>* vec};
%apply std::vector<int>* OUTPUT {std::vector<int>* vec};
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! So this example is a toy model of what I am actually working with - a huge library on which I have little control over. Custom typemaps are needed for this and I am looking for ways to explicitly select where they are applied. I've made them work in a more generic manner (as the %apply you suggested or even just matching input arguments) but I am worried about side effects i.e. getting applied on methods they shouldn't. I was wondering if there is a way to "redefine" the method as I did for the function in the interface file I included - and also why that doesn't work as expected

Comment: @LateBird If I’m understanding correctly, you have to declare the whole class again with the renamed parameter in the one method, not just the one method alone.